Group data in Power BI report without aggregate them
I have table with the following data:
enter image description here
And I'd like to make a PowerBi report such as:
enter image description here
I'd appreciate if somebody can tell me how can I do it?
Best regards,
Neu
I tried to do it with matrix visual but Power Bi Desktop always aggregate them.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


combine ID and name columns in power query
=[Company ID] & " " [Company Name]
=[Product ID]&" "&[ProductName]
=[Custeomr ID]&" "&[Customer Name]

drag the new columns in the matrix


screenshot of output
